# Indefinite integral of quadratic reciprocal of gauss hypergeometric function

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I have a question when I am solving a gauss hypergeometric equation. Specially, the gamma in the equation is a positive integer, so the general solution includes following integral. I have no idea how to solve this, does anyone can help？

Integral:
$$ \int\frac{1}{x(1-x)^2[F(1-a,1+a,1;x)]^2}dx$$

Equation:
$$ [x(x-1)D^2+(3x-1)D+k]f(x)=0$$

Comment: For what it's worth: [WolframAlpha](https://tinyurl.com/y4h4xrnu).

Comment: PS: k is a parameter, which I'm gonna change it when analyzing